# WPF - Change UI culture in callback of asynchrone task

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task, cultureinfo

In my application, the user can switch the language. Before the change is apply, a check is done. 
In full synchronous this work fine.

Now, the check is asynchronous and a callback on the UI thread set `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`.
But at the end of callback, the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` is rollback. See this example :

MainWindow.xaml :

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selected">
        <ComboBoxItem>en-US</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>en-GB</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>fr-FR</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Display</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ComboBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"A - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - {Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");
        var to = ((ComboBoxItem)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem).Content as string;
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ContinueWith(
            t => SetCurrentCulture(to),
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
    }

    private static void SetCurrentCulture(string to)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"B - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - {Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");
        var culture = new CultureInfo(to);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
}
```

Can you explain why?
How can resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith`? Instead of just `await Task.Delay(1000); SetCurrentCulture(to);`

Comment: Because the real code is more complex. I try with await/async and get the same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried setting it via the dispatcher? `Dispatcher?.Invoke(() => { //culture stuff here });`

Comment: I give a try, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Can you explain why?*

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7#Async):

> For apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6 or later versions, culture is part of an asynchronous operation's context. In other words, starting with apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6, asynchronous operations by default inherit the values of the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` properties of the thread from which they are launched.

*How can resolve this?*

Add the following switch to your `App.config` file to switch back to the behaviour seen in .NET Framework 4.5.2:

```
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture=true" />
</runtime>
```

Comment: This work, thank. The documentation say the child task inherit of the culture, but don't explain why it's rollback.

Comment: 4.6 or later, the culture is linked to the task?

Comment: @Orwel: Yes, it's part of the async method's context.